# what code should i use to automatically resize an image, whenever the browser window is made narrow?

Tags: html, css

to start with a blank screen, suppose i have the following HTML code:

```
<body>

  <div id="image">
  <img src="pic.jpg">
  </div>

</body>
```

and the CSS as:

```
#image{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

or

```
#image img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

I am confused here as there is no change in the image because the image div have the size of the image(the image dimensions are 1920*1080 pixels), and its 100% is the whole image itself.
but if i set the width to 50% there is still no change.

I just want the image to resize according to the browser, my screen resolution is 1366*768 so initially i need the image to fit that and when i resize the browser i needed the size of the image to change accordingly.

Comment: `img { max-width:100% }` should do it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas tried this too ...but no luck.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sAKAh/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes , it worked too ... i guess i need to install a new browser and try in that...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the size of the containing div doesn't change the size of the image. Set the style on the image instead:

```
#image img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jcJtM/

Comment: oh, sorry i forgot to mention that ..but i have tried that too but still there is no change

Comment: @RahulKhatri: When I try it, it works fine. I added a link to the code that I used to test it.

Comment: you are right and its working fine...but still not responding in my browser(firefox)...dont know whats wrong...
Is it because the image i am using is larger than my screen resolution? or some browser compatibility?

Comment: In responsive design, the general pattern is to do `max-width: 100%` on images, the difference being that the images won't stretch if the viewport happens to be bigger than the image.

Comment: @RahulKhatri: I tested the code in Firefox, but this is pretty basic and works the same in all browsers. It's likely that there is some other style that is interfering with this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried javaScript?

```
windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowHeight = $(window).height();

$('img').css({
    "width" : windowWidth,
    "height" : windowHeight
});

$(window).resize(function(){
windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('img').css({
    "width" : windowWidth,
    "height" : windowHeight
});
});
```